# serialize - using serialize() to pass values into database

Tags: php, sql, serialization

I have this piece of code (in a survey form)

```
<div  id="change-color0">
    <label><span class="turn-white0">01</span>Họ tên đầy đủ của bạn</label>
    <input type="text" id="input" name="content[]" class="addtodo0">
</div>
<div id="change-color1">
    <label><span class="turn-white1">02</span>Số chứng minh thư nhân dân của bạn</label>
    <input type="text" id="input" name="content[]" class="addtodo1">                   
</div>
<div id="change-color2">
    <label><span class="turn-white2">03</span>Địa chỉ thường trú của bạn</label>
    <input type="text" id="input" name="content[]" class="addtodo2">
</div>
<div id="change-color3">
    <label><span class="turn-white3">04</span>Tại sao bạn muốn trở thành học viên của dự án</label>
    <input type="text" id="input" name="content[]" class="addtodo3">
</div>
<div id="change-color4">
    <label><span class="turn-white4">05</span>Bạn nghĩ mình là ai</label>
    <input type="text" id="input" name="content[]" class="addtodo4">
</div>
<div id="change-color5">
    <label><span class="turn-white5">06</span>Trong mắt người khác bạn là ai</label>
    <input type="text" id="input" name="content[]" class="addtodo5">
</div>
<div id="change-color6">
    <label><span class="turn-white6">07</span>Bạn sợ nhất điều gì</label>
    <input type="text" id="input" name="content[]" class="addtodo6">
</div>
<div id="change-color7">
    <label><span class="turn-white7">08</span>Ước mơ của bạn là gì?</label>
    <input type="text" id="input" name="content[]" class="addtodo7">
</div>
<div id="change-color8">
    <label><span class="turn-white8">09</span>10 năm nữa bạn là ai?</label>
    <input type="text" id="input" name="content[]" class="addtodo8">
</div>
```

And i want to **input these text fields within  a row** of my db by using serialise and unserialise. 
Plus, there are lots of forms including those text fields which are in the code so how i can give them an identity to execute MYSQL query then i can call the one i want.

> ie. I want the first input of every form to show up.how can i do
>   that?

Comment: Better to separate all that into another table with key value pairs and a FK imo.

Comment: It's not quite my point bro. Thoes fields are in a survey form. And one form belongs to one user (I added fk for user table).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

well actually you should not use `serialize()` because when you call out info from SQL, you can not call exactly the one that you want.

Instead of using `serialize()`, you'd better use `implode()`to save your values into one row in your database. 
With your code snippet, I advise you should replace

> name="content"

by a specific name. And this code should work for your case

```
$arry = array("$_POST[name]","$_POST[name]","$_POST[name]");
$insert = implode(",",$array);
$sql = $conn->query("INSERT INTO yourtable_name VALUES('$insert')");
if($query){
echo "insertion grand!";
}else{
die();
```

}

Comment: 1) Implode is only slightly better, you should *normalise* your data storage. 2) This code is vulnerable to SQL injection.